# Is there a way to limit an input tag to only have one value?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

How can I limit an input tag to only have the first value? In this case it would be value1.

```html
<input value="value1
    &nbsp;value2
    &nbsp;value3
    &nbsp;value4">
```

Comment: What is your original issue that you need help with? This seems like you're asking about a proposed solution to a problem, rather than the problem itself.

Comment: It sounds like you're just looking to prohibit spaces. Please revise your post to be more clear about your requirements. See [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: Based on your revision, it's still not clear what your end goal is. Why not prepopulate the value and disable the input, or use a checkbox?

Comment: The answer to the question is yes, but that's not terribly exciting, is it? Please take the [tour] and read [ask], and browse the [meta-tag:faq]s.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using HTML 5, the best way to do this is to use the `pattern` attribute.

```html
<input pattern="\S+">
```

Comment: I seem to be able to enter anything into that input.

Comment: This just makes the `input` invalid if the value does not match the pattern.

Comment: @isherwood Yes you can enter anything, but if you try to submit the form it won't go through